# Why do I get "gradle project sync failed. basic functionality will not work properly" for intellij with Libgdx 1.6.5

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx

The program was working properly until I shut-down my PC. When I rebooted and tried opening inteelij it gave the above error with all the Libgdx calls turned red(It cannot resolve those symbols).
What is the reason for that? How can I fix it?

- Intellij IDEA 14.0.2 , libgdx 1.6.5.

Comment: What happens if you refresh Gradle dependencies? (click the 'Refresh all Gradle dependencies' icon in IntelliJ's Gradle side panel, or do a './gradlew --refresh-dependencies' from the command line). Any errors you can list?

Comment: yes, Thank you that works! It was a gradle dependency issue.Can you please explain why this could have happened?